# How to retrieve specific value from zendframework 2.0 database

Tags: php, sqlite, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hello i have a question about the zend framework. I have a database with a column having values yes and no. I wish to be able to retrieve from that column only yes values.

This is my code but no success:

```
public function getListi(array $filterBy = array())
{
$id = 'yes';
$select =  $this->sql->select();
$select->from(self::TABLE);
$select->columns(['security_maintenance']);
$select->where(array(
        'security_maintenance' => $id   
    ));
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    return $statement->execute(); 
}
```

view :

```
<div class="value-self"><?php



foreach ($domainii as $row) {

echo  $row['security_maintenance'];

                            }


?></div>
```

controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{

return new ViewModel(array(

'domainii' => $this->getDomainModel()->getListi(),

 ));
}
```

The column is called `security_maintenance`. the above does not work but when i query by id it works but that does not help me as querying by id will not help me get yes values from the `security_maintenance` column.

Answer (score 1):

Hello i got it working after doing some research into some zend documentation. This is my code:

```
public function getListii(array $filterBy = array())

{

$select =  $this->sql->select();
$select->from(self::TABLE);
$select->columns(['security_maintenance']);
$select->where->like('security_maintenance', 'yes%');
$statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
return $statement->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns you want to select.

try adding the below code

```
$select->columns(['security_maintenance']);
```

Comment: i have added that it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you add the raw SQL statement to a comment? It might make what you are trying to execute a bit clearer.

Comment: Hello i don't know how to add raw sql statement but let me explain a bit more. Can you just adjust my code above so that it fetches only yes values from security_maintenance column. The column has yes and no values. Or rather can you adjust it to count the number of yes values in the column.

Comment: i have edited code above to give you more insight please check. I also added select column and it works in that it fetches all yes and no values but i want only the yes values